# "Undefined reference to TTF_Init()" linking error when compiling C file using SDL

Tags: c, makefile, sdl

When using SDL_ttf.h in an SDL project of mine written in C. The compiler (during the linking process as object files show up and it references `ld`) spits out an error reading

```
gcc -o ttftesting ttftest.o `sdl2-config --libs --cflags` -LSDL2_ttf -ggdb3 -O0 --std=c99 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
/usr/bin/ld: ttftest.o: in function `main':
/home/first/Code/c/testing/ttftest.c:8: undefined reference to `TTF_Init'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/first/Code/c/testing/ttftest.c:9: undefined reference to `TTF_Quit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:30: ttftesting] Error 1
```

Here is the source file.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_TIMER);
   TTF_Init();
   TTF_Quit();
   SDL_Quit();
   return 0;
}
```

```
CFLAGS := `sdl2-config --libs --cflags` -LSDL2_ttf -ggdb3 -O0 --std=c99 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

Here is what is in the Makefile.

I'm not too sure what causes this error. I'm running Arch Linux and the libSDLdev libraries are all installed. SDL_tiff.h also is in /usr/include/SDL2/ yet there is a linking error. Is there something wrong with the Makefile's CFLAGS? Did I mess up the order?

Comment: typo: `-LSDL2_ttf` -> `-lSDL2_ttf`